# i need to remove line above 'WatchorDownloadVideo' or line below '[/quote]'

Tags: notepad++, regex

i need to remove line above 'WatchorDownloadVideo' or line below '[/quote]', since i have 2000 messages like this pattern.

```
[url=https://img164.imagetwist.com/i/31488/ddqvrejas5t
[url=https://i.postimg.cc/2jVXsj3Y/a-chubby
Resolution: 364 x 364 pixels
[/quote]
[url=https://img164.imagetwist.com/i/31488/hm713936i1qn
[url=https://i.postimg.cc/RVvJ3hf5/a-chubby
WatchorDownloadVideo
[url=https://gounlimited.to/
[url=https://rapidgator.net/
```

I need the following output

```
[url=https://img164.imagetwist.com/i/31488/ddqvrejas5t
[url=https://i.postimg.cc/2jVXsj3Y/a-chubby
Resolution: 364 x 364 pixels
[/quote]
WatchorDownloadVideo
[url=https://gounlimited.to/
[url=https://rapidgator.net/
```

Answer (score 0):

Search for:

```
(?is)(\[/quote\]).+?(WatchorDownloadVideo)
```

Replace with:

```
$1\n$2
```

Enable regex search.